# ASP.NET MVC Controller - Singular or Plural and Does It Matter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, naming

I know its a question which has been asked hundreds of times before but I'm stressing over the naming scheme I adopt for `Controllers` in my ASP.Net MVC application.

Say, for example, I have a model called `User` of which I have the singular ability to view, update and delete. Likewise, I also have a collection of `Users` which I can search upon giving many results.

As the routing is of the form of `{controller}/{action}/{parameter}` then my 'English' head thinks that a URL of:

`http://localhost/users/view/123` is not correct as the URL relates to a single product whereas: 
`http://localhost/user/view/123` is correct, as the user is viewing a single product

And likewise, with `Product` and `Products`:

`http://localhost/product/edit/P123456`
`http://localhost/products/?searchQuery`

This seems to make more sense (well, to me anyway) and thus means that I have to implement two `Controllers` for each `Model` but at least this means I know that the singular controller deals with a single entity whereas the plural version deals with multiple entities:

`UserController` -> Add, Edit, View, Delete 
`UsersController` -> Find, Delete

I guess the only fly in the ointment is when I come across an entity which is the same singularly as plural but within the scope of my project, this could be quite a rare thing.

I'm sorry if this is mindless babble however I'd appreciate some input from users who've gone through this before.

Comment: Voting to close as primarily opinion based. If it works correctly, then SO's opinion on this is of little importance. Use your own judgement.

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter. Users are normally not navigation through your site by typing urls, but by clicking links, buttons, menu's, ....